# Using a KmlLayer object within the Google Maps API, is it possible to allow a user to adjust the transparency of the png overlays?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

Using a KmlLayer object within the Google Maps API, is it possible to allow a user to adjust the transparency of the overlay.png features, referenced by some .kml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge it is not possible via standard google api but you can do this using jquery or some other library. KML images are just part of the DOM so if you can find the nodes you can manipulate their properties. Here is an example using jquery:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: KmlLayer KML</title> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b_opacity").click(function(){
//this will find all the images in the map canvas container. Normally you would want to target specific images by the value of src
    $("#map_canvas").find("img").css("opacity","0.4")

    })
    })


    function initialize() {
      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: chicago,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml');
      ctaLayer.setMap(map);
    }
    </script> 
    </head> 
    <body onload="initialize()"> 

      <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px;height: 600px;"></div> 
      <input type="button" value="dim the lights" class="b_opacity">
    </body> 
    </html>
```

NOTE: please bear in mind that the css property opacity does not work in IE you have to use filter:alpha(opacity=40) for IE or you can use jQuery .fade() method.

Comment: This control is cross-browser friendly and could be adapted using the jQuery above: http://www.gavinharriss.com/code/opacity-control

Answer (score 0):

This style is working for me:

```
#map > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) img[draggable="false"] {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```