# Can I manipulate a KML using Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, kml

I'm loading a KML using KMLLayer in Google Maps API v3. Is it possible to reference the polygons on the map and do things like change color or transparency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't do it like that since there are no polygons like objects in a kmllayer. From the [google docs](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers):

> The Maps API converts the provided geographic XML data into a KML
>   representation which is displayed on the map using a V3 tile overlay.
>   This KML looks (and somewhat behaves) like familiar V3 overlay
>   elements. KML  and GeoRSS point elements are rendered as
>   markers, for example,  elements are rendered as polylines
>   and  elements are rendered as polygons. Similarly,
>    elements are rendered as rectangular images on the
>   map. Importantly, however, these objects are **not Google Maps API
>   Markers, Polylines, Polygons or GroundOverlays; instead, they are
>   rendered into a single object on the map.**

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651930/using-a-kmllayer-object-within-the-google-maps-api-is-it-possible-to-allow-a-use) might be helpfull in exploring alternatives

Comment: I ended up using GeoXML as that allowed me to access the KML in Javascript.