# Save data back to Google My Maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, kml

Lets say i have an application that loads KML file from Google My Map.
Then i'd like to change some data (add descriptions to markers, create routes etc).
Finally i would like to save it back to Google My Map. Is that possible?

I haven't found anything about it in Google Maps API Docs. :(
If that is not possible with Google Maps, is there any other services that accepts KML files so i can pass changed KML or GeoXML file to them and share the result with ... friends...with anybody?

what i have now is just a dummy application https://github.com/developer88/duggerknout

Comment: According to that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793493/can-i-manipulate-a-kml-using-google-maps-api-v3?rq=1) and Google Maps API Docs i cannot edit kml files directly but i found some JS scripts that can parse KML file like xml file and create necessary objects on Google Map.