# Control Opacity of Custom Overlay with a Slider on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to control the *opacity* of a custom overlay that I have created using the Google Maps API. Nothing new here so I searched Stack Overflow and came across [this tutorial](http://www.gavinharriss.com/code/opacity-control) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651930/using-a-kmllayer-object-within-the-google-maps-api-is-it-possible-to-allow-a-us).

I'm not a JavaScript expert so I'm having some troubles. I looked through the code, and tried to adapt it with what I already have, but no luck so far. If I check for error messages in Firebug, I get the following message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

If you look through my [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/H7EAD/), you can see that the error is on Line 8 relating to `var tileCount`. I am not sure how to tweak this part of the code to make it work with what I have, which is a single image and not tiles as in the tutorial.

The slider... slides, but doesn't change the opacity. The knob/handle is missing initially as well.

Thanks for your help and guidance.

P. S. Yes, I know the custom overlay isn't perfectly aligned with the map background, but this is just an experiment/learning process.

P. P. S. I reposted this question since I realized I had inserted the wrong link.

Comment: Please fix the original question, don't repost it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to solve this issue with jquery.

Here is [a quick fix](http://jsfiddle.net/sasha_thor/H7EAD/7/) in your code.

Just a couple of a new strings:

```
TestOverlay.prototype.setOpacity = function (op) {
   //Set opacity to all layer's divs (range from 0.00 to 1.00)
  $("div.myLayer").css("opacity", op/100);
}

TestOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {
  ...
  //Set class name for opacity
  div.className = "myLayer";

  this.div_ = div;

  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
```

Opacity range is between 0 and 1. The slider from your example returns 0 - 20. Need to tune it a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How do I change the range of the slider though? I was looking into the jQuery UI slider as well. I wonder if that can be used instead? And do you know why the knob is not showing up until the slider is clicked?

Comment: You are welcome. Here is the version with jQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/sasha_thor/H7EAD/22/